# Inheriting from standard library type traits

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

When writing custom type traits, I often derive them from the standard library type traits as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct some_type_trait:
    std::is_arithmetic<T>
{};
```

However, I sometimes wonder whether inheriting from the `type` member type of the standard library type trait is cleaner:

```
template<typename T>
struct some_type_trait:
    std::is_arithmetic<T>::type
{};
```

The overall idea is that only the inheritance from `std::bool_constant` matters in the end, but the fact the we're inheriting from `std::is_arithmetic` in the first example and not directly from `std::bool_constant` (as in the second case) is observable via polymorphism or utilies like `std::is_base_of`.

The gist is that inheriting directly from `bool_constant` via `type` member type feels cleaner because it is *exactly* what we want to. However, inheriting from `std::is_arithmetic` is slightly shorter and provides essentially the same behaviour. So... is there any subtle advantage that I might be missing when picking one or the other (correctness, compile time...)? Are there subtle scenarios where inheriting from `std::is_arithmetic` might change the behaviour of the application, compared to inheriting directly from the underlying `bool_constant`?

Comment: That's some quality bikeshedding :D

Comment: FWIW, the "possible implementations" on en.cppreference.com directly inherit `std::integral_constant<bool, some_check>`. Following this "style" your example would inherit from `std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>`.

Comment: @DanielJour If I'm not mistaken, inheriting from `std::integral_constant` is mandatory for the type trait. The question is whether it's better to derive directly from `std::integral_constant` though `::type` or indirectly through the type trait itself. Maybe I didn't understand your comment :/

Comment: @Morwenn For a "user facing" type trait I'd go for neither, I'd directly inherit `std::integral_constant` but write the "requisities" (like being an arithemtic type or one of some list of types) as bool expression for the second parameter of `std::integral_constant`. This makes "extension" easier. But after all, it's just a question of preferred style, thus no answer.

Comment: Though I'm too very interested in whether there's a downside / possible pitfall to directly inheriting from a type trait in contrast to using it's `type` member type.

Comment: I think you need to inherit from `std::is_arithmetic<T>` to have the option of lazy evaluation of the trait. It is useful to have that. if you want a "clean" interface you can also have `template<class T> using some_type_trait_t = some_type_trait<T>::type`.

Answer (score 3):

The second has the minor pitfall of leaking implementation details; someone can test via function overloads if you inherit from `is_arithmetic<int>` or whatever.  This might "work" and lead to false positives.

This is an exceedingly minor issue.

You may get slightly better diagnostics by inheriting from `is_arithmetic` if your compiler dumps the base class name.

Neither of your designs composes well.  Instead:

```
template<class T>
struct some_type_trait:
  std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_arithmetic<T>{}
  >
{};
```

can be extended, as we can put any expression in there.

As I noted earlier, having the types in the error message can be helpful, so we could do:

```
constexpr bool all_of() { return true; }
template<class...Bools>
constexpr bool all_of(bool b0, Bools...bs) {
    return b0 && all_of(bs...);
}
template<class T, template<class...>class...Requirements>
struct Requires : std::integral_constant<bool,
  Requirements<T>{} &&...
  // in C++11/14, something like: all_of(Requirements<T>::value...)
> {};
```

Then we get:

```
template<class T>
using some_type_trait = Requires<T, std::is_arithmetic>;
```

which if it fails to find an overload in a tag dispatch, will generate an error that might give you a clue.

```
template<class T>
void test( std::true_type passes_test, T t ) {
  std::cout << t+0 << "\n";
}
template<class T>
void test(T t) {
  return test(some_type_trait<T>{}, t);
}
int main() {
  test(3);
  test("hello");
}
```

Sadly we don't have the equivalent of easy binding/partial application/currying in template metaprogramming.  So `f<.> = is_base_of<X, .>` is hard to express tersely.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/505c2f7eefab7573), the error messages we get is:
clang:

> ```
> main.cpp:23:10: note: candidate function [with T = const char *] not viable: no known conversion from 'some_type_trait<const char *>' (aka 'Requires<const char *, std::is_arithmetic>') to 'std::true_type' (aka 'integral_constant<bool, true>') for 1st argument
> ```

gcc:

> ```
> main.cpp:28:18: note:   cannot convert 'Requires<const char*, std::is_arithmetic>()' (type 'Requires<const char*, std::is_arithmetic>') to type 'std::true_type {aka std::integral_constant<bool, true>}'
> ```

which at least leads you to the error (that `const char*` is not `is_arithmetic`).

Comment: The compiler won't assume it's a value in that context, since it can't be a value. So inheriting from just `is_arithmetic<T>::type` is fine. Unnecessary, but fine.

Comment: @Barry Serves me right for not compiling.  Removed humourous prefix.